# JSON to CSV file conversion

Tags: json, csv

I have a JSON file

```
{
  "name": "re2",
  "count": 1806,
  "frequency": "realtime",
  "version": 5,
  "newdata": true,
  "lastrunstatus": "success",
  "lastsuccess": "Fri May 30 2014 06:02:41 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "results": {
    "collection1": [
      {
        "Title": {
          "href": "http://www.realestate.com.au/project-spec+property+%e2%80%93+helio+apartments-vic-north+melbourne-600004887",
          "text": "93 Flemington Road, North Melbourne, Vic 3051"
        },
        "image": {
          "href": "http://www.realestate.com.au/project-spec+property+%e2%80%93+helio+apartments-vic-north+melbourne-600004887",
          "alt": "93 Flemington Road, North Melbourne, Vic 3051",
          "src": "http://i2.au.reastatic.net/345x200/3a7e58fe3aefa7fd373c1b9c9879d648257dc0e7c8d35c6b7a19d261bffeff28/main.jpg"
        },
        "price": "$700,000 - $770,000",
        "title2": {
          "href": "http://www.realestate.com.au/project-spec+property+%e2%80%93+helio+apartments-vic-north+melbourne-600004887",
          "text": "93 Flemington Road, North Melbourne, Vic 3051"
        }
      },
      {
        "Title": {
          "href": "http://www.realestate.com.au/project-redmond+park-vic-carlton+north-600002807",
          "text": "300 Pigdon Street, Carlton North, Vic 3054"
        },
        "image": {
          "href": "http://www.realestate.com.au/project-redmond+park-vic-carlton+north-600002807",
          "alt": "300 Pigdon Street, Carlton North, Vic 3054",
          "src": "http://i2.au.reastatic.net/345x200/c22712b2c40db6e8017ebc6f677c9835991e3e1ab9431cfe28d0ab8ea0af43e3/main.jpg"
        },
        "price": "$830,000 - $880,000",
        "title2": {
          "href": "http://www.realestate.com.au/project-redmond+park-vic-carlton+north-600002807",
          "text": "300 Pigdon Street, Carlton North, Vic 3054"
        }
      },
      {
        "Title": {
          "href": "http://www.realestate.com.au/property-house-vic-kensington-116973739",
          "text": "60 WOLSELEY PARADE, Kensington, Vic 3031"
        },
        "image": {
          "href": "http://www.realestate.com.au/property-house-vic-kensington-116973739",
          "alt": "60 WOLSELEY PARADE, Kensington, Vic 3031",
          "src": "http://i4.au.reastatic.net/355x265/e026805577c810c6df722c171a00786f4510cb959390375d589e2d1d90ef2461/main.jpg"
        },
        "price": "SOLD $1,360,000",
        "title2": {
          "href": "http://www.realestate.com.au/property-house-vic-kensington-116973739",
          "text": "60 WOLSELEY PARADE, Kensington, Vic 3031"
        }
      },
```

I tried numerous online JSON to CSV converters which this file, and it never converts properly.

I would like a CSV file with 
Title, href, text, image, href, alt, src, price

Due to the complexity of the file, I'm having no luck with any tutorials online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it's not really possible to automatically convert JSON to CSV, since one is an object graph, and the other is essentially a table. It would be like trying to convert a Cube to a circle.

To further complicate this matter your JSON doesn't seem to be homogenous. Most obviously the first entry doesn't have a title2 instance. In order to solve this problem I would break it down into the following steps:

1. Convert JSON to proper ObjectGraph.
2. Collapse Object Graph into a flat List. Mapping fields as necessary.
3. Write out the List to a CSV.

It is not immediately obvious from your example JSON whether it is practical to read it all into memory at once, or whether you need to break it down, converting one item at a time. I doubt you will find an online tool that will do this for you, since your JSON seems incoherent and your needs are really specific.

Comment: Thanks I will try your suggestions

Comment: Cool let me know how you get on with it.

Answer (score 0):

I just released a module that makes this process easy in Node.js

```
var jsonexport = require('jsonexport');

var contacts = [{
   name: 'Bob',
   lastname: 'Smith',
   family: {
       name: 'Peter',
       type: 'Father'
   }
},{
   name: 'James',
   lastname: 'David',
   family:{
       name: 'Julie',
       type: 'Mother'
   }
},{
   name: 'Robert',
   lastname: 'Miller',
   family: null,
   location: [1231,3214,4214]
},{
   name: 'David',
   lastname: 'Martin',
   nickname: 'dmartin'
}];

jsonexport(contacts,function(err, csv){
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(csv);
});
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonexport

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called [json2flat](https://github.com/opendevl/Json2Flat).
What it does is it takes a complex JSON document and converts it to CSV format.

So what you need to do is convert your java objects into JSON format. After it
you need to pass the generated JSON into the library and it returns a 2D
representation of the JSON, you can also get the csv from it.

This library is not that mature but still it's promising.
You should give it a try.